# How do the planes change the spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes

My players are soon to head to different planes & I was wondering what changes to make for their spells while in those planes.

I tried looking for something with that material & wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you asking what the rules for doing this are (if there are any), or asking for ideas? Because we don't really do idea-generation questions here, although we can point you to other places that do. This site focuses on clearly defined issues with objectively best answers, which "give me ideas" doesn't really have.

Comment: Somebody with Planescape campaign setting material should be able to give an answer based on previous editions.

Comment: There are lots of planes. This question is much too broad as written.

Comment: What kind of changes do you have un mind? Some irrelevant ones (e.g. changing some not-costly material components) or also mechanicals modification (e.g. in the Fire Plane spells like Fireball requires only verbal components)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Also, a relevant meta, per some of the previous comments: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33569)

Answer (score 4):

[Descent into Avernus](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/baldursgate_descent) does have an Alterations to Magic section (Chapter 3: Avernus). Several spells have cosmetic changes, but other spells have more impactful changes. For example, archdevils can eavesdrop on communication spells. I don't know if the alterations apply only to the first level, or all of the Nine Hells.

[Curse of Strahd](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/curse-strahd) has an equivalent section (Chapter 2: The Lands of Barovia). This probably applies to the Domains of Dread, based on previous editions. One example from this book is that spells like Teleport simply fail, while in the lands of Barovia.

Comment: "I'm assuming that it applies to all of the Shadowfell, and not just Barovia." I think it might just apply to the Domains of Dread, rather than the entire Shadowfell. The teleport spell failing would have been a part of that, because in previous editions, magic couldn't be used to escape Ravenloft, the Demiplane of Dread (which was later merged into the Shadowfell as the Domains of Dread).

Answer (score 1):

In the 5e material, there are no rules about this specific thing(except maybe Shadow Walk), but i know that there were rules somewhere in older editions cause i remember some from the Plane of Shadow(which in 5e is known as the Shadowfell after the former got merged with the Plane of Negative Energy): Spells with the "Shadow" descriptor were cast as if you had the Maximize Spell feat, without having to use a higher level spell slot.

Furthermore, if you didn't pass a spellcraft check of 15 + level of the spell, any spell that had the "Light" descriptor, would just fizzle and the slot would be wasted; also, the areas of light were halved into that plane.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. This answer would be improved by verifying the relevant information and citing the source(s) of this information.